# Placing image inside of Label using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, basic-license-level

In ArcView, can I add an image to a label?

Assume I have the photograph path as an attribute.

Comment: Can use EMF (Enhanced Metafile Format) format to scale up labels without pixelation. But refer to Brads method below.

Answer (score 9):

in the label symbol dialog you can set the text background to a symbol marker
[image: symbol marker] select properties

then marker text background

[image: marker text bkgr]
select symbol.
Properties.
[image: pic marker symbol]
Then you have the option to select several types. One is picture marker symbol.
Which allow emf and bmp. (sorry no svg).

Another way is to use the ballon callout
[image: ballon callout]
Select symbol
there you get some choices again for the fill of the callout box.
select picture fill symbol
[image: symbol fill picture]
Again you get emf and bmp format choices.

Another choice would be to use a point feature class and put the layer in the mxd twice. Once for the symbol, and a second for the label. Use a picture marker symbol
[image: Point marker]

as the symbol and use offset xy to move it away from the original point marker.
Like this
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Very follow-able, THANKS!  Do you know how to place the image INSIDE the callout box, as apposed to replacing the callout box.

Comment: There are some options to use html in the text formatting which I think is what gets that result.  However I think that is what Jakub is referring to having problems with.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a bitmap image inside the label symbol itself but i've had nothing but trouble with this approach when it come to exporting the map to a file or outputting it to plotter/printer. The "image labels" do not render well. Some do not appear at all some do others come out rendered only partially. There is no out-of-the-box solution I know of that will allow you to dynamically display images inside of a label symbol using a path stored in the attribute.

Comment: Thanks, Is this the same method as detailed in Brad Nesom's Answer?

Comment: very similar except that I use Picture Marker symbol.

Answer (score 2):

In ArcGIS Pro, I would recommend creating your own style file and then add a marker symbol for a simple point and a picture symbol so that you can use these in a Callout text label.

For example,

[image: ArcGIS Pro Styles Area in the Catalog Window]

[image: Point and Picture Symbols in a Custom Style File]

To create a picture point symbol, you can right-click to select "New" and then fill out the "Description" tab to give the new symbol a unique name for future reference.

[image: Add New Point Symbol to a Style File]

Next, you will select the Properties tab at the bottom of the Symbol pane.
[image: Properties tab in the Symbol pane]

Click the "Layers" button.
[image: Symbol Layers button in Symbol Properties Tab]

Change the drop-down from a "Shape marker" to a "Picture marker" and then you can click the "File" button to navigate to your PNG/BMP/JPG image file.

[image: Select a Picture marker type for a point symbol]

[image: Completed Picture Point Marker]

To use the logo marker as a callout label, you need to turn on labels for your point layer, set the label field, use "No color" for the label text and create a Callout label. You do this in the Labeling ribbon and by using "Text Symbols" option.

[image: Text Symbols Option]

You set the text color in the "Appearance" area:

[image: No Color Text]

You set the logo image as a point symbol in the "Callout" area:

[image: Set Callout type to Point Symbol]

You can also specify a leader line to be drawn from your point to your logo label:

[image: Use Picture Marker Point Symbol and Leader Lines]

You can also control the position and offset of the label:

[image: Control Label Position]

I've found that it is best to keep the Appearance size small (e.g. 4 or 6 pts), but set the point symbol used for the logo to a large size (e.g. 18 - 24 pts), and then set the preferred offset to about 10 pts.

This is roughly what you get on your map:

[image: Result Map]